# Pardot authentication api not working with correct username and password

Tags: authentication, pardot

I'm having trouble getting the pardot authentication API (v4) working. After triple checking I'm sure I'm using the correct credentials.

Making a POST to

`https://pi.pardot.com/api/login/version/4?email={{email}}&password={{password}}&user_key={{pardot_user_api_key}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After many failed attempts I found [this useful blog post](https://katiekodes.com/python-pardot-api-login/) at https://katiekodes.com. The following is what's relevant to my question.

> Plus, if you’ve set up Pardot to leverage single-sign-on via Salesforce credentials, you can’t even get into the API without having a dedicated Pardot user whose “email address” isn’t the username of a user in the Salesforce org you have connected to Pardot.

And that is exactly what was causing my problem. So my solution was to create a new "dedicated" Pardot user with an alias that I set up for my email (any different email address will work).

As stated later in her blog post,

> If you have Salesforce sign-on turned in, ignore all prompts from Pardot to choose a “CRM Username” for the user you just created.

Thanks, Katie Kodes!

Comment: Is that Colorado in the background of your profile picture? It sure sparks some memories but I can't pin down which peak it might be, if so.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes it is! That would be Mt Sneffels. We were on the ridge between the Blue Lakes and Yankie Boy Basin in the photo.

Comment: Nice work! Sneffels has got to be one of the most beautiful places in the world. Anyway, welcome to SFSE! :)